# Google Maps API nearbysearch not returning the nearest locations

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on an android app and want the checkin  feature in my application. I want to get all the locations nearby my current location.

I have used the Google Places API and sending a request on the below url for getting the results.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=28.4573585,77.0332349&radius=2000&key=AIzaSyByyUldmVJqsrB_yYGlVzWF92des4DbsZ0
```

I want all the results inside 2 Km distance from my current location.

I am getting some nearby locations but not getting the nearest locations which are 100 meters or 200 meters away from the current location.

How can I get them, do I need to pass some extra parameter in the above nearbysearch request.

Also, I need to order the places according to the distance. nearest places should come first in the results.

Please help me if anyone know how to achieve this.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

By default, each nearby search returns up to 20 locations per query. However, accessing additional results as many as 60 locations, can be done by passing the value of the `next_page_token` to the `pagetoken` parameter of a new search as shown in [Accessing Additional Results](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging).

Additionally, [Nearby Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) can be refined by supplying keywords. You can put ordering on the results according to the distance by specifying `rankby=distance` in your search request and adding one or more of keyword, name, or type as required.